How to automatically adjust the figure size of a matplotlib subplot given the number of rows and columns
I am trying to create a function that will take in any number of datafiles, make an appropriate subplot, and create an appropriate figure size to plot each datafile without messing with how the title or colorbar looks. The code I have is below. My code is below:
# create figure and axes 
row = int(np.ceil(len(files)/col))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(row, col, figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi, facecolor='black') 

# loop through the counts data
for c_mean, a in zip(counts_mean, axs.ravel()): 
    img = a.imshow(c_mean, origin='lower', norm=colors.PowerNorm(gamma=.3, vmin=0, vmax=10), cmap='inferno')

# add title         
plt.suptitle('Title', fontsize=40) 

# add colorbar 
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.17, 0.88, 0.68, 0.03])
cbar = fig.colorbar(img, cax=cbar_ax, orientation='horizontal')
cbar_ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
cbar.set_label('photon counts', size=25, labelpad=-90)

# adjust spacing between the subplots 
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)


# timestamps on each of the individual plots 
for a, time in zip(axs.ravel(), times):
    t = time[0] # the label is the intial time point
    label = t[5:7] + '/' + t[8:10] + '/' + t[2:4] + ' ' + t[11:19]
    a.text(0, 10, label, color='white', size=8)

I tried using set_aspect('auto'), but this does not help. The plots are very tiny compared to a larger title
